# FluidDropOff for different products and capacities

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm working on a model in which the source block is defined by the "Arrival Table in Database". In this database I have information on the agents' arrival dates; of the primary products transported (ProductP Parameter); secondary products transported (productS parameter); of the volumes of primary products (volumePp) and the volumes of secondary products (volumePs).

I would like to connect this source block with a FluidDropOff block to unload volumePp and volumePs and to generate batches corresponding to productS and productP to be stored in different tanks.

My solution was to duplicate the agents (split) and copy the parameters of the original agent so that each of the new agents could connect to a FluidDropOff block. So "fluid to dropoff" would be the same as agent.volumePp in one block and agent.volumePs in the other block.

However, I know that this solution is neither practical nor elegant. Taking into account that I need to increase the number of products, there would be a need to considerably increase the copy of agents (which I don't believe is the best possible solution).

So, I would like to know if there is any other more valid way to solve the proposed problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just use the FluidDropOff and specify the qty to dropoff as `agent.volumeP`?

Comment: When duplicating the agent I connect them with the FluidDropOff block and do exactly that on each one of them. In other words, the first block has a quantity of agent.volumePp for dropoff and the second a quantity of agent.volumePs for dropoff.

What I would like to know is whether it is possible to perform this operation in just one FluidDropOff block, that is, a way to avoid copying agents.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean. Why don't you just use the agent in the Dropoff without copying? Maybe rewrite the question and focus on that, also add some screenshots. And simplify it to the root cause problem. Some tips for helping us help you: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow